# Is there a way to display RaisedButtons in a ButtonBar lazily?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a set of buttons I want to display on a flutter app to represent the days of the week. I currently have a widget that builds 7 RaisedButtons to represent the various days of the week. Is there a way I can do this lazily instead of having to build all 7 RaisedButtons in flutter?

Note I am using the ButtonBar widget to display the set of buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a list like following:

```
List<Widget> _optionList = List<Widget>();
```

and add as many and any kind of widget in the list, like following:

```
void setupHintButtonsUI() {
    _optionList.clear();
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      _optionList.add(
        FlatButton(),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an empty list of strings and add days name in it and then iterate through it. Create a function using the for loop like

```
var i = "";

main() {
  final List<String> days = <String>['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday','Wednesday','Thurday','Friday'];
  days.sort();
//   print(days);
  
  for (i in days){
    print(i);
  }
}
```

and then you can loop through the code and create widgets